# C++ Question: string.at function returns a "std::out_of_range" error in terminal

Tags: c++, string, indexoutofrangeexception

I've been working on this code for a while now and I keep getting the same terminal error. I have narrowed the issue down to two at functions. I've looked it up but the only answer I can seem to find is if the coder used the wrong variable in a for loop or that the variable in the at function isn't indexed properly.

Can't seem to figure out why the str.at() functions specifically are throwing errors when the variable str should be initialized. The at functions in question are the second and fourth if statements inside the do-while loop.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// start main function
int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string line;
    string str;
    int words = 0;
    int charsNotIncludingSpaces = 0;
    int charsIncludingSpaces = 0;
    int wordsEndingWithE = 0;
    int sixLetterWords = 0;
    int wordsBeginningWithVowel = 0;
    int wordsContainingATE = 0;
    int allEs = 0;
    int wordsWithAtleastTwoEs = 0;

    infile.open("USDictionary.txt");

    // read the first line from the file
    getline(infile, line);
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        unsigned int startIndex = 0;
        unsigned int endIndex = 0;      

        // get each word from the line and find the required results
        do
        {
            endIndex = line.find(' ', startIndex);          
            if(endIndex > 0 && endIndex < line.size())
            {
                str = line.substr(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                str = line.substr(startIndex);              
            }
            startIndex = endIndex + 1;

            words++;

            charsNotIncludingSpaces += str.size();

            if(str.at(str.size() - 1) == 'e')
            {
                wordsEndingWithE++;
            }

            if(str.size() == 6)
            {
                sixLetterWords++;
            }

            if(str.at(0) == 'a' || str.at(0) == 'A'
                || str.at(0) == 'e' || str.at(0) == 'E'
                || str.at(0) == 'i' || str.at(0) == 'I'
                || str.at(0) == 'o' || str.at(0) == 'O'
                || str.at(0) == 'u' || str.at(0) == 'U')
            {
                wordsBeginningWithVowel++;
            }

            unsigned int ateIndex = str.find("ate");
            if (ateIndex >= 0 && ateIndex < str.size())
            {
                wordsContainingATE++;
            }

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < str.size(); k++)
            {
                if(str.at(k) == 'e')
                    allEs++;
            }

            if (str.find_first_of('e') != str.find_last_of('e'))
            {
                wordsWithAtleastTwoEs++;
            }          
        } while (endIndex > 0 && endIndex < line.size());

        charsIncludingSpaces += line.size();

        // read the next line from the file
        getline(infile, line);
    }
    infile.close();

    /*// print the results
    cout << "Total number of words in the dictionary: "
            << words << endl;
    cout << "Total number of characters in the dictionary (not including white spaces): "
            << charsNotIncludingSpaces << endl;
    cout << "Total number of characters in the dictionary (including white spaces): "
            << charsIncludingSpaces << endl;
    cout << "Total number of words ending in the letter e: "
            << wordsEndingWithE << endl;
    cout << "Total number of 6 letter words: "
            << sixLetterWords << endl;
    cout << "Total number of words beginning with a vowel: "
            << wordsBeginningWithVowel << endl;
    cout << "Total number of words containing the substring \"ate\": "
            << wordsContainingATE << endl;
    cout << "Total number of occurances of the letter e: "
            << allEs << endl;
    cout << "Total number of words containing at least two occurances of the letter e: "
            << wordsWithAtleastTwoEs << endl;*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str.at(str.size() - 1)` is a problem when `str` is empty.

Comment: I think when line.find returns npos because it can't find the space anymore - e.g. at the last word, then it enters in the first part of the if statement - probably because you need brackets around each side of the and statement. Try adding some brackets and see if that helps.